# DJANGO - accesing some user's profile

Tags: python, django, web

I'm working on web app and currently I'm developing the profiles part. I've written part to view someones profile and this basically works fine except one thing. I can open someones profile but when I click the tabs which redirects to different part of the profile (these parts are included into block to keep the profile's main information), my code instantly switches to the currently loged user. Is there any way to get the user based on the cookies ?

this is the single advert:

```
def view_advert(request, pk, title):
    advert = Advert.objects.get(pk=pk)
    return render(request, "advert.html", {'advert':advert})
```

html

```
<small>from </small><a href="{% url 'profile' nick=advert.user.username %}">{{advert.user}}</a>
```

I open the profile of person who posted the advert (it works)

Here is one of the profile and tab:

```
@login_required
def profile(request, nick):
    user = User.objects.get(username=nick)
    user_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
    return render(request, "users_templates/profile.html", {"user_profile":user_profile})

def profile_adverts(request, user):
    user = User.objects.get(username=user)
    adverts = Advert.objects.filter(user=user)
    context = {
        "objects":adverts,
        "no_data":"No other adverts",
        "user":user
    }
    return render(request, "profile_templates/general_list.html", context)
```

html from profile.html to access tab:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'all_adverts' user=user %}" role="tab" aria-selected="false">All adverts</a>
```

Appreciate for help.

edit for @revliscano

general_list.html

```
{% extends "users_templates/profile.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load static %}
{% block adverts %}
    {% if objects|length > 0 %}
        {% for object in objects %}
            <div class="work-container">
                <h3>{{object.title}}</h3>
                <h4><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>Jan 2017 to <span class="badge badge-info">Current</span></h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        <div class="work-container">
            <h3>{{no_data}}</h3>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock adverts %}
```

profile html:

```
{% extends "main.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<div class="row mt-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 ">
            <div class="card left-profile-card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <img src="{{user_profile.avatar.url}}" alt="" class="user-profile">
                        <h3>{{user_profile.user.username}}</h3>
                        <p>World of Internet</p>
                        <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center mb-3">
                            <i class="fas fa-star text-info"></i>
                            <i class="fas fa-star text-info"></i>
                            <i class="fas fa-star text-info"></i>
                            <i class="fas fa-star text-info"></i>
                            <i class="fas fa-star text-info"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="personal-info">
                        <h3>Personal Information</h3>
                        <ul class="personal-list">
                            <li><i class="fas fa-briefcase "></i><span>Web Designer</span></li>
                            <li><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt "></i><span> New York</span></li>
                            <li><i class="far fa-envelope "></i><span>like @example.com</span></li>
                            <li><i class="fas fa-mobile "></i><span>1234564343</span></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-9">
            <div class="card right-profile-card">
                <div class="card-header alert-primary">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#" role="tab" aria-selected="false">Comments</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#" role="tab" aria-selected="false">All adverts</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#" role="tab" aria-selected="false">Timeline</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#" role="tab" aria-selected="false">Document</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#" role="tab" aria-selected="false">Event</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
                        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab">
                            {% block adverts %}
                            {% endblock adverts %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Why having `href="{% url 'all_adverts' user=user %}"` for a tab? I think it should be `href="#"`, right?

Comment: @revliscano by saying tab I mean button which redirects you to another part

Comment: Alright. What's the view that handles `all_adverts`?

Comment: @revliscano profile_adverts which I linked above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **profile.html** you're passing the user profile as `user_profile` in the context data, but then here `href="{% url 'all_adverts' user=user %}"` you're referring to it as `user` (which by default is the same as `request.user`, i.e, the authenticated user).

Try changing it for

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'all_adverts' user=user_profile.user.username %}" role="tab" aria-selected="false">All adverts</a>
```

Comment: same :( I receive NoReverse regarding this <a href="{% url 'profile' nick=user.username%}

Comment: But did you change anything else than what I suggested?

Comment: Just your suggestion

Comment: Is this happening after you click on the tab, right?

Comment: Exactly. I can access the profile, but tabs gives me the error

Comment: Are you sharing the entire code of `profile_adverts` view? Also, can you share general_list.html? (You can edit your question)

Comment: I showed the entire profile_adverts and just added general_list.html

Comment: Okay, I see it's extending from 'profile.html'. I will need to take a look to the entire 'profile.html' file, because that is being loaded as well when returning the response from `profile_adverts` view.

Comment: Why now all of the <a> of your tabs have href="#"???? The NoReverseMatch comes when you have a link to an incorrect url, and that's what I'm trying to spot.

Comment: I reseted hrefs to start over. I think I have the idea now - I will share with the result soon

Comment: as I thought i was right :) You helped my though in tracking the error. Thanks

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Cheers!